# video share on facebook

Tags: ios, ios6

I am making a test app through that I want to post a video on facebook. I am using latest sdk of facebook. But I am not able to post it on facebook. The video is coming from web service.
How to convert video url in nsdata and mu code is below

```
     NSString *astrUserid=[[mutTimeline objectAtIndex:indexpath] objectForKey:@"user_id"];
            NSString *astrImageid=[[mutTimeline objectAtIndex:indexpath] objectForKey:@"image_id"];
            NSString *astrExt=[[mutTimeline objectAtIndex:indexpath] objectForKey:@"ext"];
            NSString *aStrDisplyimage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://followme.pmcommu.com/audio/user/%@-%@.%@",astrUserid, astrImageid,astrExt ];
            NSURL *aimageurl=[NSURL URLWithString:aStrDisplyimage];


            NSString *filePathOfVideo = [aimageurl path];

            NSLog(@"Path  Of Video is %@", filePathOfVideo);
            NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathOfVideo];
            //you can use dataWithContentsOfURL if you have a Url of video file
            //NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:shareURL];
            //NSLog(@"data is :%@",videoData);
            NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           videoData, @"video.mov",
                                           @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                           @"Video name ", @"name",
                                           @"description of Video", @"description",
                                           nil];

            if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
            {
                [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                             parameters:params
                                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                          if(!error)
                                          {
                                              NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                              //[self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video uploaded"];
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                              //[self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Denied" message:@"Try Again"];
                                          }
                                      }];
            }
            else
            {
                NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                        @"publish_actions",
                                        nil];
                // OPEN Session!
                [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone  allowLoginUI:YES
                                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                                     NSError *error) {
                                                     if (error)
                                                     {
                                                         NSLog(@"Login fail :%@",error);
                                                     }
                                                     else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
                                                     {
                                                         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                                                      parameters:params
                                                                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                                                   if(!error)
                                                                                   {
                                                                                       //[self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Video uploaded"];

                                                                                       NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
                                                                                   }
                                                                                   else
                                                                                   {
                                                                                       //[self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Denied" message:@"Try Again"];

                                                                                       NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                                                   }

                                                                               }];
                                                     }
                                                 }];
            }
```

I am new for that can any one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or this will help you for upload and streaming video, i think

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

// Specify App ID and permissions
NSDictionary *options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey: FACEBOOK_ID,
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"video_upload"],
                          ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends}; // basic read permissions

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
            ACAccount *facebookAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];


            NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"description": aMessage};


            SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                      URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"]
                                                               parameters:parameters];

            [facebookRequest addMultipartData: aVideo
                                     withName:@"source"
                                         type:@"video/mp4"
                                     filename:@"video.mov"];

            facebookRequest.account = facebookAccount;


            [facebookRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData* responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse, NSError* error) {
                if (error == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"responedata:%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                }
            }];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Access Denied");
        NSLog(@"[%@]",[e localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: thank you for replay but my Question is that my video is come from web server hoe to get nsdata from that i was tryed nsdata=[nsdata conttent ofurl:url]; but data=nill

Comment: "Www-Authenticate" = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.\"";
    "X-FB-Debug" = "0wOUsuV3ggbqDJ6uTwbKA/7zBKYfDpzGXlXF9VYQ6zWCWBVC1EU0yazO2IQlnPkv8/7oHWK0gm2z6CiK3M5New==";
    "X-FB-Rev" = 1326514;

Answer (score 0):

Get the publish permission

```
NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
    [permissions release];
```

Try this

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                                   @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                       nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"]]
```

Comment: i am geting nsdata=nill

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)facbookSharng {

NSLog(@"Permission for sharing..%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].permissions);

if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"contact_email"])
{
    FBSDKShareVideo *ShareVideo = [FBSDKShareVideo videoWithVideoURL:appDelegateObj.finalVideoUrl];
    ShareVideo.videoURL = appDelegateObj.finalVideoUrl;
    FBSDKShareVideoContent *ShareContnt = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
    ShareContnt.video = ShareVideo;
    [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:ShareContnt delegate:self] 

      // write the deleate methdo for post ID..
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue